# Keyboard function keys behaving as if fn is constantly pressed*

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 21.04

*in most cases.

When I press FN+F#, I get the same functionality as on windows. F5 to 7 handle music... F3 opens my mail...

However when I dont, there are some function keys that when pressed do almost the same thing.

Note that i am using a laptop with this keyboard. however not even the function keys on the laptop's keyboard have the same functionality...

On windows, F5 to F7 is for music, F8 to F10 is for volume..

On ubuntu

F5 and F6 (without fn) dim or lighten my laptop's keyboard backlight.
F7 to F9 handle music control. F10 through F12 handles volume. With 11 and 12 being volume up/down and 10 being mute/unmute.

My laptop's keyboard does NOT do this. It doesnt even have this double functionality... It just has the functionality you'd expect from whats written under the function keys, when you press them WITH fn.

My keyboard doesnt have this problem on windows. I have tried multiple layouts but that doesnt fix it.

I have also tried using xev.

My laptop's F3 results `state 0x2010, keycode 69 (keysym 0xffc0, F3)`, My keyboard's F3 results `state 0x2010, keycode 128 (keysym 0x1008ff4a, XF86LaunchA)` instead.

Edit:
My keyboard is a Drevo Gramr V2 TE

Comment: Could you simplify/clarify your question? All I can see is "Ubuntu isn't Windows".

Comment: What? I am simply stating the behavior i get from windows and the behavior i get in Ubuntu, If you were unsure of what i meant with that, It is that i cannot use my function keys properly, for example, in programs, because they are already mapped to do system based actions.